# Switch form in panel

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a panel with somes button when you click on it, it show specific form inside the panel. The panel is blocked on the first form showed even when you try to remove it.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
        dashboard.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(dashboard);
        panel1.Controls.Remove(settings);
        dashboard.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        dashboard.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dashboard.Show();
        settings.Hide();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
        settings.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Remove(dashboard);
        panel1.Controls.Add(settings);
        settings.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        settings.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        settings.Show();
        dashboard.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use forms as controls. Use user controls. That's what they are for. If you have multiple in the same container overlapping, just call `BringToFront` on the one you want the user to see.

Comment: Ok thanks BringToFront function seem to work!